# A Tale of Urns and Balls

Tags: probability

I got the following situation:

2 urns with 2 whites and 3 blacks
2 urns with 1 white  and 4 blacks
1 urn  with 4 whites and 1 blacks

A ball is drawn from an urn (***and*** this urn is selected at random). The ball is white.
Now, a second ball is drawn from the ***same*** urn. What is the probability of getting a black?

ATTEMPT: The urn is selected at random, and we have no further informations about it, so it smells of deception. I think we got to consider only the general set of 10 whites and 15 blacks.
So, having independent trials, we calculate $\frac{10}{25} \times \frac{15}{24}$. (Alternatively, using conditional probability formula).

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These things can be tricky, and unless one has a very well developed intuition, I would advise a formal conditional probability calculation.

The probability of white on the first pick turns out to simplify to $\frac{2}{5}$. You got that a quick way. It can also be done more slowly.

Next we compute the *conditional probabilities*, **given** white on first pick, that it came from the various urns.

The conditional probabilities turn out to be $\frac{1}{5}, \frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{10},\frac{1}{10},\frac{2}{5}$. Thus the probability that the second is black is
$$\frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{3}{4}+ \frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{3}{4} +\frac{1}{10}\cdot \frac{4}{4} + \frac{1}{10}\cdot \frac{4}{4}+\frac{2}{5}\cdot \frac{1}{4}.$$

We leave it to you to verify that the conditional probabilities are what they are, and to fill in any missing details.

Comment: Thanks. Be Ai="The first white was drawn from i-th urn". Be B="The second is white" (problem asked for a black second, but I follow you, doesnt change nothing).<br> Now we calculate conditional probability for, e.g., A1: P(A1|B)=P(intersection)/P(B). We already know P(B)=2/5, so it remains the intersection, that turns out to be P(A1)xP(B|A1), and this apllying conditional probability formula the other way; so [1/5*2/5]/(2/5)=1/5, as you pointed out.

Comment: Now, let C="second is white". We gotta calculate P(C|A1) (and same for every Ai). But you seem to avoid this formal calculation and use probability of union of **disjoint** events. Why this and not P(C|Ai)?

Comment: I have changed from white to black. Thanks. Minor shift, complement. I did "calculate" $\Pr(C|A_1)$, and so on. For example, the probability that second is black, given that we drew from the first urn, is $\frac{3}{4}$ (there are $4$ balls left, and one of the white balls is gone). So one could call it, and write it, as a Bayes' Formula calculation.

Comment: A couple of further questions, if I may: 1) What allow us (formal argument) to assign probability 2/5 directly, on the first draw.  2) You said the second part of solution is Bayes formula application. This is because the events (C|Ai) do partition the entire space of outcomes? Please provide a full formal argument, like you should explain this during a regular college lesson. I want to make sure to NOT misunderstand what you explained me. Thanks again ;)

Comment: White on first pick can happen in $5$ ways; (i) chose first urn and got white; (ii) chose second and got white: and so on. Probability of white on first pick is $(1/5)(2/5)+(1/5)(2/5)+(1/5)(1/5)+(1/5)(1/5)+(1/5)(4/5)$. This simplifies to $2/5$. Standard "tree" or conditional probability calculation, the first term $(1/5)(2/5)$ is probability of choosing the first urn times (conditional) probability of white given we are selecting from first urn. Similar for all the others.

Comment: Ok, I think I have understood. Urns perform the disjoint decomposition of the sample space on the first pick as well as on the second. So we apply the so-called "total probability theorem". The rest is done by Bayes formula. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. It is important to seek clarity.

Comment: Beg your pardon, but I rethought to exercise. Let's go to the point where we calculate the conditional probability of drawing a black second, GIVEN the urn is the i-th. Correctly, you multiplicate the probability of i-th urn (1/5), by the probability of black in the same urn. This is fine and similar to calculation of an expectation. But a formal argument would require P(C|Ui) (as I already pointed out), and this is equal to P(C intersect Ui)/P(Ui). How we calculate the probability of the above INTERSECTION? P(Ui|C)P(C) does not help, since we don't know P(Ui|C).

Comment: I would prefer to solve this exercise whithout using the notion of expectation. Do you refer to total probability theorem? (Decomposition of an event via intersection with a disjoint union of events)? Thanks.

Comment: Let $W$ be event white on first, and $B$ the event black on second. We want $\Pr(B|W)$. This is $\frac{\Pr(W\cap B)}{\Pr(W)}$. I take it you have no trouble with $\Pr(W)$: the event $W$ is a disjoint union of $5$ simple events. The same applies to $\Pr(W\cap B)$. The event $W\cap B$ can happen in $5$ pairwise disjoint ways. One of them is drew from first, drew white, then black. This has probability $(1/5)(2/5)(3/4)$. The other $4$ are calculated similarly. Then divide by $\Pr(W)$.

Comment: I got it this way. Now all is perfectly clear. Thanks again, and pardon me for reopening the argument.

Comment: I wanted to use a calculation that was formally correct but fairly close to the intuition. So in the main answer I preferred to avoid the calculation of my last comment. To me it has an excessively mechanical character.